# Get rid from the padding in Lightning component tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

Is it possible to get rid from the padding in Lightning component tab?

Here is the padding:

[image]

I was able to find the class which adds the horizontal padding. The class is `.slds-template_default`. But I do not know how to prevent the addition of the class.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that the padding needs to be removed across all pages in your app. If so, your best bet is to create a custom page template and tweak the CSS there. Something like below, but I conveniently changed the component version to 41 so I could throw in some quick `<style>` in the markup, but I am sure you can improvise to meet the latest version standards.

And oh, you will have to recreate your record pages to use this new template, but perhaps for greater good?

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:recordHomeTemplate" description="Header, Subheader, Right Sidebar, Footer">

    <!-- NOTE:  Although the most recent version available as of this note is 43.0, the version of this component has been intentionally set to 41.0 -->
    <!--        Version 42.0 onwards the <style> tag has been disabled from markup, so below will not work. -->
    <!--        Below CSS reduces padding between component place holders (the blue background you see behind the components when placed in a page) -->
    <style>
        .slds-template_default {
            padding: 0rem;
        }
    </style>

    <aura:attribute name="header" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="subHeader" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="left" type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="right" type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="footer" type="Aura.Component[]"/>

    <aura:attribute name="flexiSize" type="Integer" default="{!$Browser.isDesktop? 4 : 6}"/>

    <div class="slds-m-bottom_x-small">
        {!v.header}
    </div>

    <div class="slds-m-bottom_x-small">
        {!v.subHeader}
    </div>

    <div class="slds-m-bottom_x-small">
        <lightning:layout >
            <lightning:layoutItem class="slds-p-right_x-small" flexibility="grow" size="12" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="8" largeDeviceSize="8">
                {!v.left}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow" size="12" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="{!v.flexiSize}" largeDeviceSize="{!v.flexiSize}">
                {!v.right}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>

    <footer role="contentinfo">
        {!v.footer}
    </footer>

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've added a negative margin to my outermost element :

```
  margin: -0.75rem;
```

I works well, but the problem with this solution that Salesforce can change their design anytime...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The spacing comes from the .slds-template_default class which adds padding to the container of our component. In order to fix this, we need to add negative margins & increment the height of our component to fill the bottom.

1. First, make sure your component has only one element

   **GOOD!**

   ```
   <aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
       <div></div>
   </aura:component>
   ```

   **BAD!**

   ```
   <aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
   </aura:component>
   ```
2. Then, place this in your CSS file

   ```css
   .THIS {
       margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--lwc-templateGutters, 0.75rem));
       margin-right: calc(-1 * var(--lwc-templateGutters, 0.75rem));
       margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--lwc-templateGutters, 0.75rem));
       margin-bottom: calc(-4 * var(--lwc-templateGutters, 0.75rem));
       border-radius: var(--lwc-spacingNone);
       height: calc(100% + 2 * var(--lwc-templateGutters, 0.75rem));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Using negative values on the top or left margins can cause the application to escape the sandbox and introduces clickjacking vulnerabilities.

[Please check the below link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_clickjacking_enable.htm&type=5)

If we used in negative margin then your app will reject by Salesforce Security Review Team

Comment: I think you meant this to be a comment on Peter Tempfli's answer. You'll be able to post comments when you gain a little more reputation; until then, please make sure to post answers that directly answer the main question. Thanks!