# LWC Get rid of the padding in Lightning component tab

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have a lightning web component tab in our system. We just want to get rid of Salesforce template padding (blue area in the picture). Does anyone have any idea?

Basically, what we need is LWC way of below Aura question:
[Get rid from the padding in Lightning component tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228318/get-rid-from-the-padding-in-lightning-component-tab)

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't a good way to do this in LWC. Even the Aura component example is hacky. Salesforce's ecosystem is supposed to make unified styling as easy as possible. I don't recommend you implement a hacky method for the small impact it will have.

If you continue to implement the change, here is my suggestion - I recommend you use the example you provided which uses a custom lightning page template. You can still use your LWC inside custom page templates (Aura) and even Aura components in general.

For a terrible LWC approach - You can use document.querySelector() to select elements outside of your components shadow dom, but it is not advised. For example, you could find the component that contains the padding -
[image]

Then remove it via javascript -

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Demo extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        document.querySelector('[id="brandBand_2"]').style.paddingTop = '0'; 
    }
}
```

[image]

That being said, please don't do that because of the following -

1. The target of your querySelector() will change based on if your component is in a home page, record page, or app page. My example works for my home page, but not a record page.
2. Salesforce could change their markup at any time and it could break your selector.
3. The querySelector() will error out in the page builder preview.
4. Salesforce tries to make styling consistent across the platform. Don't go against the grain!

Stick with the Aura component method as mentioned above.